# Preventing tampering with save game data (iOS)

Tags: swift

I am creating an iOS game with In-App purchases for "Coins" and I wish to prevent (or make it very difficult) for the user to simply edit the save-game file and increase the number of "Coins" without paying for them. I am only concerned with non-jailbroken devices.

I have created a `GameData` class that roughly follows the first part of [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2468-how-to-save-your-game-s-data-part-2-2), with the following aims:

1. Whenever the game data is saved, a hash is stored in the keychain
2. Whenever the game data is loaded, if the hash doesn't match the keychain then mark the data as invalid (presumably tampered with)
3. No false positives: if the data hasn't been tampered with it should not be marked as invalid

**GameData.swift**

```
import Foundation
import KeychainAccess
import CommonCrypto

enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case coins
}

class GameData: Codable {
    private static let FILE_NAME = "gamedata.json"
    private static let KEYCHAIN_KEY = "GameDataVerification"

    private static let keychain = Keychain()
    public static let shared: GameData = {
        if let gameData = GameData.load() {
            return gameData
        }
        return GameData()
    }()

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "GameDataSave", qos: .background)

    private(set) public var invalid: Bool = false

    public var coins: Int

    init() {
        self.coins = 0
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.coins = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .coins) ?? 0
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(self.coins, forKey: .coins)
    }

    public func save() {
        // Don't save if the data is invalid.
        guard !self.invalid else { return }

        self.queue.async {
            // TODO: Handle the case that the game data is written successfully but the hash isn't.
            do {
                // Save the game data to file.
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                let data = try encoder.encode(self)
                try data.write(to: GameData.filePath())

                // Save the hash of the game data for verification.
                try GameData.keychain.set(GameData.hash(data), key: GameData.KEYCHAIN_KEY)
            } catch {
                print("Unable to save game data:", error)
            }
        }
    }

    private static func load() -> GameData? {
        do {
            // Load the game data from file.
            if let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: GameData.filePath().path) {
                // Load the hash of the saved game data.
                let storedHash = try GameData.keychain.get(GameData.KEYCHAIN_KEY)!

                // Decode the stored data.
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let gameData = try decoder.decode(GameData.self, from: data)

                // If the hashes don't match, set a flag on the game data.
                let hashesMatch = storedHash == GameData.hash(data)
                if !hashesMatch {
                    print("Hashes don't match!")
                    gameData.invalid = true
                }
                return gameData
            }
            print("No game data found.")
            return nil
        } catch {
            print("Unable to load game data:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }

    private static func filePath() -> URL {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        return url!.appendingPathComponent(GameData.FILE_NAME, isDirectory: false)
    }

    private static func hash(_ data: Data) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        data.withUnsafeBytes {
            _ = CC_SHA512($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
        }
        return digest.map({ String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }).joined(separator: "")
    }
}
```

**Basic usage:**

```
print(GameData.shared.coins)
GameData.shared.coins += 100
GameData.shared.save()
```

Comment: Is `var coins` the only variable that needs to be saved as game state, or is this a simplified example?

Comment: This is a simplified example; I didn't think there was much point expanding the size of the code sample with 10-20 similar variables.